# What difference between some-prefix-gcc and gcc --target=some-prefix?

Tags: gcc, gnu-toolchain

I want to use another version of `gcc` (newer), but don't want to replace original `<some-prefix>-gcc` executable.

Which compiler flags do I have to use to emulate the `<some-prefix>-gcc` behaviour? I know about `--prefix` and `--target` flags during building, but I don't want to build a specific version of gcc.

Problem with `/my/new/gcc --target=some-prefix` in different tool chains (`<some-prefix>-ld`, `<some-prefix>-as`). So, I want to use my version of GCC as front end and the original tool chain as back end (not only executables, includes/libs too).

Which additional flags can help me to tell `gcc` to use the `<some-prefix>-as` as back end?

Comment: You've got a commandline handler frontending for your compilers, what's the problem? You know how to make gcc do  what you want, you're at the place in the code to make it do that, do it that way.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `-B dir` to tell gcc to look in `dir` for the other executables it needs, but you can't tell it to use a different `<some-prefix>` because that's set when gcc is built. You also can't (generally) mix headers and libs from one version of gcc with another version, they are intended to be used together with the release they came with.

You could create a new directory with symlinks to the backend tools you want, naming the symlinks as gcc expects to find them, then use `-B` to tell it to look in that dir. But don't be surprised if it fails to work.